# Google Plus Login Integration Error iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus

Hi i am trying to integrate google+ login on my iOS app. I've followed the instructions form this [link](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started).

The examples are working fine but when i tried to implement on my app it is getting this

`errorTerminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSBundle gpp_registerFonts]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x16af620'`

I have added the following frameworks
[Image](http://screencast.com/t/GlFRYlDNOPZU)
Any help

Code: in viewdidload of my view

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;  // Uncomment to get the user's email

// You previously set kClientId in the "Initialize the Google+ client" step
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin, // defined in GTLPlusConstants.h
                 nil];
// Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
signIn.delegate = self;
```

After that I add this functions

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication annotation: (id)annotation 
{
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url
        sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                annotation:annotation];
}
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
        error: (NSError *) error
{
    NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}
```

And i add a button in my view of class GPPSignInButton.

Comment: did u configure the plist

Comment: yes i've added URL Types

Comment: exactly where u get the error put some code, that would be helpful

Comment: where is the code .. ?

Comment: where u are adding the sign in button

Comment: hay did u added "GooglePlus.bundle" ... ? if not added,  add it, is in the SDK

Comment: yes i ve added the googleplus.bundle

Comment: wait i will upvote u dicuss in chat

Comment: still getting the same error .. ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41412/discussion-between-shan-and-souvickcse)

Comment: Forgot all above just follow below link steps https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi the problem is with the -ObjC. Though i ve added the -ObjC earlier but i dnt know why it was not working but when i delete and again add it starts working. Maybe i copy-paste it earlier so there is any space or something.

Answer (score 3):

in the app delegate u need to set client id and once u hav set this you dont need to set it again in ViewController

did u added `GooglePlus.bundle` if not added add it to your project

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kGoogleplusClientID;
    [GPPDeepLink setDelegate:self];


    ......    
 }


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation 
 {
    return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url  sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
 }
```

next in your myView u can do something like this

```
 //in .h file
 @class GPPSignInButton;

 @interface ViewController : UIViewController

 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *signInButton; //sign in button


 .....



//in .m file

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{  
      [GPPSignInButton class]; //for sign in button u need to put a view and set its calss  name as `GPPSignInButton` and connect to IBOutlet of ur signInButton
      [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
      [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;


     GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
     signIn.delegate = self;
   ........ 
           //if u are settings are all correct u will logged in successfully


}
```

Comment: @souvickcse check how u set the login button see my answer

Comment: and also did u added "Other Linker Flags: -ObjC"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using custom button with IBOutlet connection. Delete outlet connection in Storyboard and try again. It will work.

Comment: actualy i am using it in a single view. And trying to use the google plus button.