# On Google plus integration in iOS app crashes

Tags: ios

i am trying to implement google plus login but app crashes and get the following error
+[NSBundle gpp_registerFonts]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x34ce2f0c

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Plus Login Integration Error iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042554/google-plus-login-integration-error-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that uou have added -ObjC to Other Linker Flags in the build settings of your app.